# Is every riemann-integral the limit of equidistant riemann-sums?

Tags: integration, analysis

So, I know that the riemann-integral is sometimes defined as the limit of equidistant riemann-sums like this:

[image]

which is probably fallacious, as the existence of this limit wouldn't actually imply riemann-integrability. (e.g. for the dirichlet-function)

However, what I wonder is, if the riemann-integral for any function that actually IS riemann-integrable can be calculated like that? I once read, that it is true for every continuous function, but it seems to me that only boundedness would be required for proving this, which already follows from riemann-integrability, but not necessarily continuity.
So, can every riemann-integral be calculated like this, provided it exists?

Comment: Equidistant partitions are still partitions, and if the mesh of the partition goes to $0$, then the Riemann sum converges to the Riemann integral, provided the Riemann integral exists.

Comment: A [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512073/a-criterion-for-riemann-integrability).

Comment: Yes. This is immediate from the _definition_ of Riemann integrability!

Comment: For "nice" discontinuous functions, break up the calculation at the points of discontinuity.

Comment: Of related interest is the fact that in the definition of Riemann integration using partitions whose norms approach zero, with arbitrarily selected "evaluation points" (not just left or right endpoints) within each subinterval associated with each partition, is suffices to restrict oneself to equi-width partitions. See Theorem 2 (p. 789) in Jingcheng Tong, [*Partitions of the interval in the definition of Riemann's integral*](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/002073901753124673), **International Journal of Mathematical Education in Science and Technology** 32 #5 (2001), pp. 788-793.